# Is it possible to sum all weighted values without adding helper columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following two tables set up:

A table of survey questions

| Group | Question | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | Q1 | 0.4 |
| G1 | Q2 | 0.3 |
| G1 | Q3 | 0.3 |
| G2 | Q4 | 0.5 |
| G2 | Q5 | 0.5 |
| G3 | Q6 | 0.8 |
| G3 | Q6 | 0.1 |
| G3 | Q7 | 0.1 |

In reality it has a lot more questions, but this should be enough for demonstration purposes.

In addition I have a table with all the answers and "subjects" (each respondent answers each question concerning N subjects):

| Subject | Question | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | Q1 | 9 |
| S1 | Q2 | 8 |
| S1 | Q3 | 11 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Sn | Q7 | 4 |

Now.. what I would normally do is add an xlookup/index-match column to the response-table (last one) to pull each weight, multiply with the score, and then work from there.

I wonder, however, if there is a more elegant solution that does not require this.

What I want is to have a table that does summarizes the data by

1. multiply each question by its weight (using some lookup)
2. group by subject and group (and sum values)
3. Present in following table:

| X | S1 | S2 | S3 | ... | Sn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | calc | calc | calc | calc | calc |
| G2 | calc | calc | calc | calc | calc |
| G3 | calc | calc | calc | calc | calc |

Preferably in one formula. I think this should be possible by using the filter function, xlookup, or similar, but I have been stumped in both my own attempts and by my googling skills.

Thanks in advance..

Edit: Tried the below method. I get correct values for questions in group 1, but 0 for the others. I inspected the matrices produced in a, b, c, d there and they are as follows:

a:

[image: A]

b:

[image: B]

c:

[image]

d:

[image]

I believe the problem occurs in the SUM(IFERROR(d*c;0)), because in this example the first 3 rows of c are all errors, and the d only has values in the first 3 rows, so those will be 0, and when c gets to its values, d has run out.

Link to example workbook:
[Workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19hvQGnizP2Nf6KS_CB5DoB6p_ybu3SZA/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115979033753091328480&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: I would look at sumifs() but would start by doing the first step like weighting a response correct of each question.

Comment: I would too, but I was wondering if it is possible to do without!

Comment: What about the `=SumProduct()` function?

Comment: So, no helper column, no use of sumifs(), wqhat about sum(), sumif(), sumproduct(), countif(), countifs()?

Comment: Sure... every formula is ok. Just not helper columns.

Comment: Hmm how do I upload a workbook? No "attachment" or upload link anywhere in Edit besides for images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am not wrong this should work for you, using <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> Function

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,FILTER($B$2:$C$9,$A$2:$A$9=$I2),
     b,FILTER($F$2:$G$6,J$1=$E$2:$E$6),
     c,INDEX(TAKE(a,,-1),XMATCH(TAKE(b,,1),TAKE(a,,1))),
     d,INDEX(TAKE(b,,-1),XMATCH(TAKE(a,,1),TAKE(b,,1))),
     SUM(IFERROR(d*c,0)))
```

---

Comment: I'm not familiar with the DROP function but why is it necessary in this one? Why not just use `FILTER($C$2:$C$9...` instead of dropping the column afterwards? Also, should Sn get a value for G1/G2 in this example? (since Sn only has a value for G3 (Q7).

Comment: @Notus_Panda Yes you are right, thanks for highlighting that, see i have updated ones, lmk if there is anything I am missing again.

Comment: This ALMOST works. I might have done something wrong though. For me I got 0 for all values for G2 and G3. Note that my tables are slightly different (using excel tables). I did an inspection of the matrices created in C and D in the formula. C has a lot of errors. For G1 it is ok, because the errors come at the bottom, but in G2 for instance, the errors come in the middle. Hence d*c evaluates to 0 for the rows of D where there is a score, then D runs out of elements and C gets to its weights.

Comment: Note that in my actual form, all data is in tables. I have groups 1, 2, 3 and 4, with the following number of questions in each: G1->4, G2->3, G3->2, G4->4 for a total of 13 questions. I have 5 "subjects" (actually these are suppliers, and this is an evaluation of suppliers for a procurement)

Comment: Hi @gudal, could post a shareable workbook link in the following comments, so that ï can see and understand, what has actually gone wrong on your end, as far as the answer given it should work as per the data given in the post, if there is something, i need to see it. So that i can improvise the answer

Comment: Thanks. I will have to anonymize it heavily if I are to do so.. Give me a few hours then.

Comment: Added a link in post

Comment: @gudal alright let me check. Let me know what is your excel version?

Comment: I added a second condition to the B filter and it works. Marked as solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @gudal aah that sounds great, sorry for the late response, i was looking at your excel.

Comment: Now that you have had a look at my excel... Due to how my tables were structured i "had to" add a choosecol (or whatever it is called with english language on functons). My question: Did I have to, or is there a better way? And... would this still work if my answers table or my other tables were unsorted?

Comment: Hi @gudal thanks again for replying, I think `CHOOSECOLS()` were not required, because you could have use `TAKE()` or `DROP()` to exclude the columns and yes it should work even when it is not sorted as I have used `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` function. But note Spill array i.e. dynamic array formula dont work with Structured references however in your query it would work because it is working with reference to single cell.